# MSSQL: Filtering on a list of conditions using the like operator

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has an 'Indications' column as follows-

```
Indication
-----------
Insomnia
Depression
Anxiety
```

I have another table

```
Condition                Code
------------------------------
Short term insomnia      1
Transient insomnia       2
Chronic depression       3
Post natal depression    4
```

I want to use the column in table 1 to filter table 2 using a like operator.
So, I want the query to look for `'%Insomnia%`,`'%Depression%'`, etc. and give all the entries having those terms in it.

However, I want to filter all the indications in one query rather than doing this for every single indication.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join both tables with the `LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT
    C.*,
    I.Indication
FROM
    Condition AS C
    INNER JOIN Indication AS I ON C.Condition LIKE '%' + I.Indication + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM Condition C
WHERE EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM Indications I WHERE  C.Condition LIKE '%' + I.[Indication] + '%'
)
```